# Roll out effect on a div when scroll to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, css-transitions

What I would like to achieve is for the div with .skill-container to roll out when you scroll down to it on the page. Like this JFiddle, but on scrolling instead of hover.

http://jsfiddle.net/fernandosavio/u8MS3/

or this: http://jsfiddle.net/zT9Y8/7/

I've tried a few things, including something with stop().animate but it wasn't working. I think this is on the right track..

CSS

```
.slideOut {
   width: 600px;
}

.skill-container {
    width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: rgba(27,176,206,.6);
    float: left;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease .05s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease .05s;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease .05s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease .05s;
    transition: all .5s ease .05s;
}
```

JS

```
$('.skill-container').each(function(){
var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (imagePos < topOfWindow+200) {
        $(this).addClass("slideOut");
    }
});
```

Comment: Be aware that calling `.offset()` will trigger a [forced synchronous layout](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/avoid-large-complex-layouts-and-layout-thrashing?hl=en). If you do this on every scroll event, you will quickly kill performance on slower browsers/devices. Make sure you throttle the amount of times you run this code in response to a scroll event (use underscoreJS/lodash's `_.throttle()` method), and that you read values first, then make any modifications afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Waypoints http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/ as a good plugin that can do this.

If you do it with your own code your going to need to use the scroll event

```
 $(window).scroll(function(e){
    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
 });
```

Then don't forget to Unbind the scroll event when you don't need it

```
//Unbinds Scroll Event
function unbindScroll(){
    $(window).unbind("scroll");
}
```

And also consider throttling the amount of times the Scroll event code runs using Timeout

```
function setScrollTimer(){
    unbindScroll();
    scrollTimer = window.setTimeout(function(){bindScroll()}, 10);
}
```

jQuery Waypoints does all this for you though